# Changing tab icons in Komodo Edit

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I would like to change the default blank tab icons in Komodo, but couldn't find the right CSS selectors.
I created userChrome.css file that works and I could target the language-specific tabs by:

```
#tabbed-view tabs > tab[label$=".js"]
```

But the default tab icons always stay on top, no matter which selectors i use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I changed default tab icons in Komodo Edit 7.1:

```
.tab-icon {
    display: none;
}
.tab-image-left {
    background-image: url(chrome://famfamfamsilk/skin/icons/page.png) !important;
    width: 16px !important;
    height: 16px !important;
}
#tabbed-view tabs > tab[label$=".js"] .tab-image-left {
    background-image: url(chrome://famfamfamsilk/skin/icons/page_white_code.png) !important;
}
```

This code should go into userChrome.css